Visual Studio 2022, There were deployment errors. Continue? while running a simple stored procedure
I am receiving this strange error. **"There were deployment errors. Continue? **"I am new to stored procedure. Downloaded AdventureWorks database. and wrote my first stored procedure. Till now it was working fine. Now I am getting this error. Not a simple stored procedure runs, even hello world. Please help in resolving the issue.
screenshot
restarted VS, and windows but to no use.
